# My progress bar is behind my current time how do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you go to [this link](https://tunechestmusic.000webhostapp.com/) and click on the 2nd or 3rd song you will notice that the progress bar is slower than the actual current time after about 10 seconds. This is my Java script code:

```
var timer;
var percent = 0;
var audio = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");
audio.addEventListener("playing", function(_event) {
  var duration = _event.target.duration;
  advance(duration, audio);
});
audio.addEventListener("pause", function(_event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
var advance = function(duration, element) {
  var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
  increment = 10/duration
  percent = Math.min(increment * element.currentTime * 10, 100);
  progress.style.width = percent+'%'
  startTimer(duration, element);
}
var startTimer = function(duration, element){ 
  if(percent < 100) {
    timer = setTimeout(function (){advance(duration, element)}, 100);
  }
}
```

If your looking for the full code check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k09ydn2u/1/). Also I assume it has something to do with the track length because in the fiddle I use 40 second songs and it works fine.
If anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated.